# Custom user registration in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I would like to set up user system in Wordpress, which is not limited to writing post or comment. Instead I would like to store custom user data (in my case users are tutors) for example the subject they teach and the price they charge. How could i do it with PHP or Sql?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here:

A) modify the registration form/process and request the users/tutors to input additional data when they register on the site; this will also require you to provide them with a user friendly interface screen where they can update/edit their information.  What I usually do is create a view to display the user's info on the front end and then when loading that page check if the user is viewing their own profile and if so, load additional edit options in line with their data - I then use AJAX to allow them to update their own info.

B) if you want to manually manage this info yourself then simply have the users/tutors fill out a form and then you can update/edit a custom post-type called `sevenine-tutor` that you'll have to register/create in the system.

In theory you'd want these users managing their own profiles so option A) is probably the right route to pursue.

Questions like this are hard to answer because they're purely theoretical so there could be numerous ways to tackle them and whether an answer is correct or not is purely subjective.  My advice would be to break your idea up into chunks and try tackling functions one by one and if you get stuck on something, then post relevant code here or to wordpress.stackexchange.com and get answers to very specific technical questions.